# Inverse of a multiplicative arithmetic function.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $f$ be a multiplicative arithmetic function. Define $$h(p^2) = f(p)^2 - f(p^2)$$ for any prime $p$. Then $h(p^2) = f^{-1}(p^2)$ for any prime.

Proof. Let $p$ be prime. Then consider $$f * h (p^2) = \sum_{d|p^2} f(d)h(\frac{n}{d}).$$
I think the peoblem does not quite make sence since I don't know how $h(1)$ and $h(p)$ are defined.

Not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: You're right that you don't know the definitions of $h(1)$ and $h(p)$. However, $f^{-1}(n)$, the Dirichlet inverse of $f(n)$, is a unique function somewhere in the world (we know a theorem to that effect), so it has a well-defined value at $p^2$. So you're being asked to prove that that value is exactly $f(p)^2-f(p^2)$. To do so, you will probably have to determine what $f^{-1}(1)$ and $f^{-1}(p)$ are, it's true—but note that this doesn't really have anything to do with $h$ or its other values.

Comment: So you mean I should find $f^{-1}$ directly ? I know there is an induction formula to determine the multiplicative inverse of Dirichlet convolution. I think that formula might help solving this problem.

Comment: Yes that's right. Honestly the way the problem is worded is kind of silly; just saying "Compute $f^{-1}(p^2)$ in terms of the values of $f$" or "Show that $f^{-1}(p^2) = f(p)^2-f(p^2)$ would have accomplished the same thing with less confusion.